# How to dock a view inside of a XtraGrid.GridControl?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a DevExpress XtraGrid.GridControl in a Winforms project that I'm using with a Master/Detail setup with multiple tables in a dataset that is bound at runtime. The visual behavior of the grid is somewhat erratic in that there is a dragable bar at the bottom of the visible grid section in the GridControl, that does not expand to the size of the control when the size of the data changes.

In my implementation, the GridControl is docked to fill the tab page that it occupies, and with this single exception works as expected. However the grid itself is only using half of the visible area available on the form. This is an issue because the data is over a full screen of rows and detail rows, but the user must manually resize the view by dragging the size bar to the bottom of the screen.

I'm manually expanding each view as they are registered, though this issue persists even when I do not automatically perform this and allow the user to expand them by clicking the plus sign. Here is the section of code that programmatically expands a view:

```
For x As Integer = 0 to v.RowCount - 1
  For y as integer = 0 to v.GetRelationCount(x) - 1
    v.ExpandMasterRow(x, y)
  Next
Next
```

I have looked for a way to set a GridView object to 'dock' inside the GridControl, but have not found a way to. Is there a way to make the data fill the GridControl/View automatically? Thank you for any assistance on this issue.

Comment: It would help if you can put some print screen, maybe i can help

Comment: I've uploaded an image of the grid before and after resizing of the grid to the following URL: [link](http://postimg.org/image/b4uqzho9f/)

Comment: I have some additional information. The grid does display more lines when there is an additional row in the top-most table of the dataset. For instance, if my parent table has 1 row then the grid will show 50%, but if there are two rows then it shows the full screen's height. It seems that even though there are plenty of child rows to fill the screen, the grid is sizing itself off of the parent row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when the XtraGrid creates a sub view, it ignores the DetailHeight of the parent view, in favor of the DetailHeight on the child view. Setting the view's DetailHeight as it is registered corrected the problem.

```
Private Sub grdMaster_ViewRegistered(sender As System.Object, e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.ViewOperationEventArgs) Handles grdMaster.ViewRegistered
  Try
    Select Case e.View.GetViewCaption()
      Case "parent_child"
        Dim view As Grid.GridView = e.View
        view.DetailHeight = 10000
    End Select
  Catch ex As Exception
    'handle error.
  End Try
End Sub
```

Thank you all for your assistance and help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll want to have a GridView for each DataTable you want to show in a GridControl, but when you do all in runtime, you will need to initialize the same Gridview for each datasource/DataTable you want to show.

```
//GridView view;
view.PopulateColumns();
view.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = true;
view.BestFitMaxRowCount = 10000;   // or less ? depends on your data vs preformance
view.BestFitColumns();
// you may want to limit some of the columns width
foreach (GridColumn item in view.Columns)
{
    item.Width = (item.Width > 1000) ? 1000 : item.Width;
}
//GridControl ctrl;    // if you do this in form load you  need to do a force initialize afterwards.
ctrl.ForceInitialize();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, however I have already generated and attached the views as needed. The grid is just not correctly expanding its internal size to match its external boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

By your print screen, it seems that you are docking everyting inside one panel or tab. But that panel is not docked in the Form itself, isn't that the problem?

You should always do :

```
GridControl1.DockStyle = DockStyle.Fill;
```

and also dock the container:

```
Panel1.DockStyle = DockStyle.Fill
```

Comment: There is a tab control on the form, that has a tab page for this grid. The page is in essence the panel and expands and contracts properly with the form. The grid is docked inside the page and also expands and contracts appropriately. The line that you see in the screen capture is inside of the XtraGrid control, and is movable within the control's confines. The views are generated inside of the control's space, and as such are not something I can dock.

Comment: To be honest, is kind of hard to help you with such an specific issue, if you could replicate this in simpler code and then edit you questino with the Designer code of you sample we can replicate and then really inderstand the issue, that for me is still unclear. Im jus trying to help :)